# Return string with new string containing URL?

Tags: java, string

I have string as follows:

```
String tweet = "#Insurgent is No. 1 in 72 of 76 markets where it opened this weekend #BoxOffice http://t.co/Y1Cdjl5JQ8 http://t.co/442WKZVcOq";
```

I want it to convert about string into following:

```
"#Insurgent is No. 1 in 72 of 76 markets where it opened this weekend #BoxOffice <a>http://t.co/Y1Cdjl5JQ8</a> <a>http://t.co/442WKZVcOq</a>";
```

So I want to check strings for web URL and wrap it with anchor tags.

Comment: only two urls in this string.?

Comment: this is just example. I want to wrap any http url I find in string and wrap it up with <a> and end with </a>

Comment: `string.replaceAll("\\b(http://\\S+)", "<a>$1</a>")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj perfect avinash thanks dude.. i will test on few more scenarios else will ping you

Comment: than i guess Avinash is rite, u have to play with regex